# One page in landscape while others in Portrait in generating PDF using XSLT

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, xsl-fo

I am generating a PDF using following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-family = "Helvetica" font-size = "10px">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master margin-bottom="0.5cm" margin-left="0.75cm" margin-right="0.75cm" margin-top="0.5cm" master-name="first" page-height="27.9cm" page-width="21.6cm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-bottom = "0.5cm" margin-top = "0.25cm"/>
                    <fo:region-before extent = "0cm"/>
                    <fo:region-after extent = "0.5cm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <xsl:for-each select="Rowsets">
                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="first">
                    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
                        <fo:block font-size="9pt" line-height="3pt" text-align-last="justify">

                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:static-content>
                    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                        <fo:block font-size="8pt" line-height="6pt" text-align-last="justify">
                            Report
                            <fo:inline id="Date">
                                Date [currentDate]
                            </fo:inline>
                            <fo:leader leader-pattern = "space"/>
                            Page
                            <fo:page-number/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:static-content>
                    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                        <xsl:for-each select="Rowset">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="position()=25">
                                    <fo:table border-color="black" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
                                        <xsl:variable name="columns">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="count(Columns/Column)" />
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="Columns/Column">
                                            <xsl:choose>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="30pt"/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()=2">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="55pt"/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()=3">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="32pt"/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()=5">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="35pt"/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()=4">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="60pt"/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()=8">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="40pt"/>
                                                </xsl:when>

                                                <xsl:when test="position()=12">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="100pt"/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                                    <fo:table-column/>
                                                </xsl:otherwise>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                        <fo:table-body font-size="10pt">
                                            <fo:table-row height="13pt">
                                                <fo:table-cell background-color="#000000" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" padding-left="5pt" padding-top="5pt" number-columns-spanned="{$columns}">
                                                    <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="center" color="#FFFFFF">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="Columns/Column[1]/@Description" />
                                                    </fo:block>
                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                            </fo:table-row>
                                            <xsl:if test="Columns/Column[2]/@Description='true'">
                                                <fo:table-row height="13pt">
                                                    <xsl:for-each select="Columns/Column">
                                                        <fo:table-cell background-color="#CCCCCC" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" padding-left="5pt" padding-top="5pt">
                                                            <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="left">
                                                                <xsl:value-of select="translate(@Name,'_',' ')" />
                                                            </fo:block>
                                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                                </fo:table-row>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="Row">
                                                <fo:table-row height="13pt">
                                                    <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                                                        <fo:table-cell background-color="#FFFFFF" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" padding-left="5pt" padding-top="5pt">
                                                            <fo:block font-weight="normal" text-align="left">
                                                                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                                            </fo:block>
                                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                                </fo:table-row>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </fo:table-body>
                                    </fo:table>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="Columns/Column[1]/@Description = 'Break'">
                                            <fo:block page-break-before="always" />
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <fo:table border-color="black" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
                                                <xsl:variable name="columns">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="count(Columns/Column)" />
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                                <xsl:for-each select="Columns/Column">
                                                    <fo:table-column />
                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                                <fo:table-body font-size="10pt">
                                                    <fo:table-row height="13pt">
                                                        <fo:table-cell background-color="#000000" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" padding-left="5pt" padding-top="5pt" number-columns-spanned="{$columns}">
                                                            <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="center" color="#FFFFFF">
                                                                <xsl:value-of select="Columns/Column[1]/@Description" />
                                                            </fo:block>
                                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                                    </fo:table-row>
                                                    <xsl:if test="Columns/Column[2]/@Description='true'">
                                                        <fo:table-row height="13pt">
                                                            <xsl:for-each select="Columns/Column">
                                                                <fo:table-cell background-color="#CCCCCC" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" padding-left="5pt" padding-top="5pt">
                                                                    <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="left">
                                                                        <xsl:value-of select="translate(@Name,'_',' ')" />
                                                                    </fo:block>
                                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                                        </fo:table-row>
                                                    </xsl:if>
                                                    <xsl:for-each select="Row">
                                                        <fo:table-row height="13pt">
                                                            <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                                                                <fo:table-cell background-color="#FFFFFF" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" padding-left="5pt" padding-top="5pt">
                                                                    <fo:block font-weight="normal" text-align="left">
                                                                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                                                    </fo:block>
                                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                                        </fo:table-row>
                                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                                </fo:table-body>
                                            </fo:table>
                                            <fo:block text-indent="2pc" space-after="7pt" space-before.minimum="6pt" space-before.optimum="8pt" space-before.maximum="10pt">
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </fo:flow>
                </fo:page-sequence>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works just fine. Only problem is For Rowset 25, I have too many columns and it does not look good so I want to change the orientation to landscape just for Rowset 25 of my XML while I want others as Portrait.

The part of the XML for which I need landscape orientation looks like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<Rowset>
    <Columns>
        <Column Description="Box Number" MaxRange="100" MinRange="0" Name="Tote" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Tote"/>
        <Column Description="true" MaxRange="100" MinRange="0" Name="Status" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Status"/>
        <Column Description="" MaxRange="100" MinRange="0" Name="Shift" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Shift"/>
        <Column Description="" MaxRange="100" MinRange="0" Name="Lot" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Lot"/>
        <Column Description="" MaxRange="100" MinRange="0" Name="Qty" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Qty"/>
        <Column Description="" MaxRange="100" MinRange="0" Name="Date" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Date"/>
        <Column Description="" MaxRange="100" MinRange="0" Name="User" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="User"/>
        <Column Description="" MaxRange="100" MinRange="0" Name="Cavity" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Cavity"/>
        <Column Description="" MaxRange="100" MinRange="0" Name="Mainbody_Cavity" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Mainbody_Cavity"/>
        <Column Description="" MaxRange="100" MinRange="0" Name="Canc_By" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Canc_By"/>
        <Column Description="" MaxRange="100" MinRange="0" Name="Canc_On" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Canc_On"/>
        <Column Description="" MaxRange="100" MinRange="0" Name="Comment" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Comment"/>
    </Columns>
    <Row>
        <Tote>1</Tote>
        <Status>Inspection Stock</Status>
        <Shift>1</Shift>
        <Lot>12345678</Lot>
        <Qty>10</Qty>
        <Date>01/13/2016 09:14:26</Date>
        <User>XYZ</User>
        <Cavity>K11</Cavity>
        <Mainbody_Cavity>P11, P21, P31</Mainbody_Cavity>
        <Canc_By>ABCXYZ</Canc_By>
        <Canc_On>01/13/2016 09:20:26</Canc_On>
        <Comment>Cancelled.</Comment>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Tote>2</Tote>
        <Status>Inspection Stock</Status>
        <Shift>1</Shift>
        <Lot>12345678</Lot>
        <Qty>10</Qty>
        <Date>01/13/2016 09:14:26</Date>
        <User>XYZ</User>
        <Cavity>K11</Cavity>
        <Mainbody_Cavity>P11, P21, P31</Mainbody_Cavity>
        <Canc_By>ABCXYZ</Canc_By>
        <Canc_On>01/13/2016 09:20:26</Canc_On>
        <Comment>Cancelled.</Comment>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Tote>3</Tote>
        <Status>Inspection Stock</Status>
        <Shift>1</Shift>
        <Lot>12345678</Lot>
        <Qty>10</Qty>
        <Date>01/13/2016 09:14:26</Date>
        <User>XYZ</User>
        <Cavity>K11</Cavity>
        <Mainbody_Cavity>P11, P21, P31</Mainbody_Cavity>
        <Canc_By>ABCXYZ</Canc_By>
        <Canc_On>01/13/2016 09:20:26</Canc_On>
        <Comment>Cancelled.</Comment>
    </Row>
</Rowset>
```

This Rowset appears at position 25.

Is it even possible to achieve it?

Thanks !

After Kevin's answer, I tried with following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-family = "Helvetica" font-size = "10px">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master margin-bottom="0.5cm" margin-left="0.75cm" margin-right="0.75cm" margin-top="0.5cm" master-name="first" page-height="27.9cm" page-width="21.6cm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-bottom = "0.5cm" margin-top = "0.25cm"/>
                    <fo:region-before extent = "0cm"/>
                    <fo:region-after extent = "0.5cm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
                <fo:simple-page-master margin-bottom="0.5cm" margin-left="0.75cm" margin-right="0.75cm" margin-top="0.5cm" master-name="landscape" page-height="21.6cm" page-width="27.9cm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-bottom = "0.5cm" margin-top = "0.25cm"/>
                    <fo:region-before extent = "0cm"/>
                    <fo:region-after extent = "0.5cm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <xsl:for-each select="Rowsets">
                <xsl:for-each select="Rowset">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="position()=27">
                            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="landscape">
                                <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
                                    <fo:block font-size="9pt" line-height="3pt" text-align-last="justify">
                                        <fo:inline id="DNumber">
                                DNumber [DNumber]
                            </fo:inline>
                                        <fo:leader leader-pattern = "space"/>
                                        <fo:inline id="DNumberVersion">
                                Version [DNumberVersion]
                            </fo:inline>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:static-content>
                                <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                                    <fo:block font-size="8pt" line-height="6pt" text-align-last="justify">
                            Eletronic Batch Record
                            <fo:inline id="Date">
                                Date [currentDate]
                            </fo:inline>
                            <fo:leader leader-pattern = "space"/>
                            Page
                            <fo:page-number/>
                        </fo:block>
                                </fo:static-content>
                                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                                    <fo:table border-color="black" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
                                        <xsl:variable name="columns">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="count(Columns/Column)" />
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="Columns/Column">
                                            <xsl:choose>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="30pt"/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()=2">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="55pt"/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()=3">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="32pt"/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()=4">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="35pt"/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()=5">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="55pt"/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()=6">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="40pt"/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()=7">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="35pt"/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()=8">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="58pt"/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()=9">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="55pt"/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()=10">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="51pt"/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()=11">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="55pt"/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="position()=12">
                                                    <fo:table-column column-width="75pt"/>
                                                </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                                    <fo:table-column/>
                                                </xsl:otherwise>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                        <fo:table-body font-size="10pt">
                                            <fo:table-row height="13pt">
                                                <fo:table-cell background-color="#000000" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" padding-left="5pt" padding-top="5pt" number-columns-spanned="{$columns}">
                                                    <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="center" color="#FFFFFF">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="Columns/Column[1]/@Description" />
                                                    </fo:block>
                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                            </fo:table-row>
                                            <xsl:if test="Columns/Column[2]/@Description='true'">
                                                <fo:table-row height="13pt">
                                                    <xsl:for-each select="Columns/Column">
                                                        <fo:table-cell background-color="#CCCCCC" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" padding-left="5pt" padding-top="5pt">
                                                            <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="left">
                                                                <xsl:value-of select="translate(@Name,'_',' ')" />
                                                            </fo:block>
                                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                                </fo:table-row>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="Row">
                                                <fo:table-row height="13pt">
                                                    <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                                                        <fo:table-cell background-color="#FFFFFF" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" padding-left="5pt" padding-top="5pt">
                                                            <fo:block font-weight="normal" text-align="left">
                                                                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                                            </fo:block>
                                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                                </fo:table-row>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </fo:table-body>
                                    </fo:table>
                                </fo:flow>
                            </fo:page-sequence>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="Columns/Column[1]/@Description = 'Break'">
                                    <fo:block page-break-before="always" />
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="first">
                                        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
                                            <fo:block font-size="9pt" line-height="3pt" text-align-last="justify">
                                                <fo:inline id="DNumber">
                                DNumber [DNumber]
                            </fo:inline>
                                                <fo:leader leader-pattern = "space"/>
                                                <fo:inline id="DNumberVersion">
                                Version [DNumberVersion]
                            </fo:inline>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:static-content>
                                        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                                            <fo:block font-size="8pt" line-height="6pt" text-align-last="justify">
                            Eletronic Batch Record
                            <fo:inline id="Date">
                                Date [currentDate]
                            </fo:inline>
                            <fo:leader leader-pattern = "space"/>
                            Page
                            <fo:page-number/>
                        </fo:block>
                                        </fo:static-content>
                                        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                                            <fo:table border-color="black" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
                                                <xsl:variable name="columns">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="count(Columns/Column)" />
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                                <xsl:for-each select="Columns/Column">
                                                    <fo:table-column />
                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                                <fo:table-body font-size="10pt">
                                                    <fo:table-row height="13pt">
                                                        <fo:table-cell background-color="#000000" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" padding-left="5pt" padding-top="5pt" number-columns-spanned="{$columns}">
                                                            <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="center" color="#FFFFFF">
                                                                <xsl:value-of select="Columns/Column[1]/@Description" />
                                                            </fo:block>
                                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                                    </fo:table-row>
                                                    <xsl:if test="Columns/Column[2]/@Description='true'">
                                                        <fo:table-row height="13pt">
                                                            <xsl:for-each select="Columns/Column">
                                                                <fo:table-cell background-color="#CCCCCC" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" padding-left="5pt" padding-top="5pt">
                                                                    <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="left">
                                                                        <xsl:value-of select="translate(@Name,'_',' ')" />
                                                                    </fo:block>
                                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                                        </fo:table-row>
                                                    </xsl:if>
                                                    <xsl:for-each select="Row">
                                                        <fo:table-row height="13pt">
                                                            <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                                                                <fo:table-cell background-color="#FFFFFF" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" padding-left="5pt" padding-top="5pt">
                                                                    <fo:block font-weight="normal" text-align="left">
                                                                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                                                    </fo:block>
                                                                </fo:table-cell>
                                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                                        </fo:table-row>
                                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                                </fo:table-body>
                                            </fo:table>
                                            <fo:block text-indent="2pc" space-after="7pt" space-before.minimum="6pt" space-before.optimum="8pt" space-before.maximum="10pt">
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:flow>
                                    </fo:page-sequence>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I'm geeting follwoing error:

```
[ERROR] [Renderer_1]org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: Property ID "DNumber" (found on "fo:inline") previously used; ID values must be unique within a document! (See position 4:-1)
```

Not sure what's wrong? How can I give inline ID at both the placs without creating this error?

Comment: Is it possible ? Sure. Change you XSL to throw a page-sequence for each row-set and select the appropriate matsre (landscape versus portrait) depending on whatever properties trigger the wider table.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. But can you please give an example how to achieve that in my given XSLT? I tried your suggestion but could not succeed :(

Comment: First ... create a master that is landscape. Change your code above include that page master. I am not here to write code for you, I am here to help you solve your problems.

Comment: Your answer showed no attempt at any code what so ever. Sorry you are offended. I posted you answer in pseudo-code and you can resolve as there are 1000 ways to do it and we cannot guess at it.

Comment: You should actually create a new question as you (now) have a new issue. Your XSL is creating in the same XSL FO (at least) two objects with the same ID. Simply put, an ID should be unique. I do not see anything like DNumber in your XML.

Comment: For instance, I see this:
<xsl:for-each select="Rowsets">

<xsl:for-each select="Rowset">

....

<fo:inline id="DNumber">

That makes the id the string "DNumber" and you do it over and over again. So it is repeated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a sample:

```
<pages>
<page type="landscape">
    <p>Hello I am a landscape page</p>
</page>
<page type="portrait">
    <p>Hello I am a Portrait page</p>
</page>
<page type="landscape">
    <p>Hello I am a landscape page</p>
</page>
<page type="landscape">
    <p>Hello I am a landscape page</p>
</page>
<page type="square">
    <p>Hello I am a square page</p>
</page>
<page type="portrait">
    <p>Hello I am a Portrait page</p>
</page>
<page type="square">
    <p>Hello I am a square page</p>
</page>
</pages>
```

Using this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/pages">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-family = "Helvetica" font-size = "10px">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="portrait" margin-bottom="0.5cm" margin-left="0.75cm" margin-right="0.75cm" margin-top="0.5cm" page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in">
                <fo:region-body margin-bottom = "0.5cm" margin-top = "0.25cm"/>
                <fo:region-before extent = "0cm"/>
                <fo:region-after extent = "0.5cm"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="landscape" margin-bottom="0.5cm" margin-left="0.75cm" margin-right="0.75cm" margin-top="0.5cm" page-height="8.5in" page-width="11in">
                <fo:region-body margin-bottom = "0.5cm" margin-top = "0.25cm"/>
                <fo:region-before extent = "0cm"/>
                <fo:region-after extent = "0.5cm"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="square" margin-bottom="0.5cm" margin-left="0.75cm" margin-right="0.75cm" margin-top="0.5cm" page-height="6in" page-width="6in">
                <fo:region-body margin-bottom = "0.5cm" margin-top = "0.25cm"/>
                <fo:region-before extent = "0cm"/>
                <fo:region-after extent = "0.5cm"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <xsl:for-each select="page">
            <fo:page-sequence>
                <xsl:attribute name="master-reference">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block font-size="42pt"><xsl:value-of select="p"/></fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That produces this PDF:

[image]

As you can see, all different page sizes.

Now, you provided no information about your way of selecting the page size and you have no page templates that are any size other than one. This should be enough information to answer the question "is is even possible to achieve it". I am trying to get you to present us with information that helps us help you.

Comment: Please have a look at updated XSLT in the question. I am getting  error.

Comment: Can you please check my answer and give your comments?

Comment: @SohamShah, if your question was answered you should accept the answer and then ask a different question with your new issue.